# What do the "0 0" in "flex: 0 0 33%" stand for?

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm currently learning about flex and saw this line in Bootstrap 4's column classes:

```
.col-md-4 {
    flex: 0 0 33.3333%;
}
```

What are the corresponding properties for the two `0 0`?

Comment: How about simply read the docs?, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex¨ ... and a great tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex):

## [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

> This is a shorthand property that sets `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis`.

It's useful to think of them as proportional arguments about how much the element should grow or shrink. `0 0 33%` basically just means "take up a third", and don't "grow" or "shrink" any more, proportional to the other elements.

In more detail:

## [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)

> The flex-grow CSS property specifies the flex grow factor of a flex item. It specifies what amount of space inside the flex container the item should take up. The flex grow factor of a flex item is relative to the size of the other children in the flex-container.

## [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink)

> The flex-shrink CSS property specifies the flex shrink factor of a flex item. Flex items will shrink to fill the container according to the flex-shrink number, when the default width of flex items is wider than the flex container.

## [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)

> The flex-basis CSS property specifies the initial main size of a flex item. This property determines the size of the content-box unless specified otherwise using box-sizing.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! Just a bit of an addition if I may: Can you explain why they picked `0` for `flex-grow`? In my head, I want the item to grow on a scale of `1`, not `0`, this `0` makes me think that the item shouldn't be even visible.

Comment: @DanielMoss, when you're more familiar with these properties you'll understand why `flex-grow` doesn't work that way. In this case, `flex-grow: 1` (or any other value) wouldn't make any difference, because `flex-basis` has already consumed all the free space.

Comment: @Michael_B Thank you very much. Cameron as well. Selected this as the answer.

Comment: Here is a GREAT demo that just came into my inbox via the Smashing newsletter. It's a great example of what those properties do: https://codepen.io/shshaw/details/EbjvbQ/?mc_cid=5076304c94&mc_eid=ecfa0ee9a9

Comment: Actually I was able to practically understand  from this link : https://www.cssmine.com/ebook/flexbox-items